# cross-browser compliant webpage

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I created my index.html page as well as my styles.css page. When I run it from Notepadd++, it looks good on Chrome, but not on the other browsers IE and Firefox. But when I upload it to my hosting site, it looks all spaced out on Chrome and still messing on the other two browsers.  The link to my site is http://79.170.40.54/romeyb.com/ and I've included my code.  How can I resolve the cross-browser compliant issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>

    <title>Home</title>

    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style-ff.css"       type="text/css">-->

</head>

<body>
<br>

<script src="script.js"></script>

<div id="header">

    <div id="logo">
        <h1><img style="width: 200px; height: 100px;" alt="romeyb" src="images/logo.png"></h1>
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li class="home"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                    <li class="about"><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
                    <li class="blog"><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
                    <li class="resume"><a href="resume.html">resume</a></li>
                    <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--navbar closing div-->
    </div><!--logo closing div-->  

</div><!--header closing div--> 

<div class="gap"></div>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Welcome to RomeyB.com <br></h1>
        <p>Welcome to the website, romeyb.com, created by Romey B.   This website is to showcase my skills in HTML and         CSS,      and content will be added as I go.</p>  

        <p>I will eventually add Javascript and jQuery to this site and will also design as I go.</p>  

        <p>I'm also learning Wordpress to become familiar with building websites using the Content Management System (CMS)      technology, and to begin blogging in which I will discuss my personal battles with social anxiety, growing up without           a father, and growing up as a non-stereotypical Black American.</p>  

        <p>I hope you enjoy the content that I will be posting here and I thank you for sharing this journey with me.</p> 
            <br>
</div><!--content closing div-->

<div id="right">

    <p>This portion will consists of ads and possibly some updates to the   website.  Haven't decided yet.</p>
    </div><!--right closing div-->

    <div id="footer">&copy; 2015 romeyb.com</div><!--footer closing div-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it may be helpful to include an image to how it is suppose to look

Comment: The CSS downloaded from your server seems to have some spurious characters in it. For example: `|#content {` - what's that leading `|`?

Comment: You have a broken link: http://79.170.40.54/romeyb.com/script.js "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Although I don't know if you do any style change from JS. So this may not be the issue

Comment: You have a problem with floating I used to have problems with this all the time. Also yes the | characters shouldn't be there, and im sure the * is unintentional.

Answer (score 0):

For cross browser sites, that's always a problem. As you get into Web Development you'll learn to tackle those issues. And also IE will always give you a headache!

Now remember this is one solution for getting it nice and next to each other without crazy gaps and gives you control of the gap. There are multiple ways to solve HTML and CSS problems. This is just the way I usually do it.

For your content and right problem. You have one floating to the right and the other to the left. usually when you want them near each other or stacked against each other you float them both left. And then for a gap have  a "filler" div in between them.

This is similar to your code I just scaled it down so I could see it myself:

```
#content {
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width:1000px;
  marign: 0 0 20 20;


}
#filler{
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width:50px;
  marign: 0 0 20 20;

}

#right {
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
  width:100px;
  marign:5 5 20 20;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="content">
    //your content
</div><!--content closing div-->

<div id="filler"> 
</div>

<div id="right">
  //your ads
</div><!--right closing div-->
```

It worked in my chrome and firefox . It looked nice. 
Here is something that helped me with floating divs and understanding it:

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

And this is old but still relevant I think:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/

And please if I missed something let me know or edit this post!